# Convert html output to image

Tags: html, r, image, output

I'm using **R** formattable package to render some data frames but the output is html ( it opens the browser after I run the script ).

The thing is I'm trying to render those tables under PowerBI which accepts **R** scripts but need the output to be an image (like a ggplot) not html. But I don't know how I can do it.

I've looked into R2HTML and htmlwidgets packages but I still didn't find a solution with those. ( I may have made some mistakes ).

Here is the dummy code I'm working with:

```
library(formattable)
DF <- data.frame(Ticker=c("", "", "", "IBM", "AAPL", "MSFT"),
             Name=c("Dow Jones", "S&P 500", "Technology", 
                    "IBM", "Apple", "Microsoft"),
             Value=accounting(c(15988.08, 1880.33, NA, 
                                130.00, 97.05, 50.99)),
             Change=percent(c(-0.0239, -0.0216, 0.021, 
                              -0.0219, -0.0248, -0.0399)))
DF
##   Ticker       Name     Value Change
## 1         Dow Jones 15,988.08 -2.39%
## 2           S&P 500  1,880.33 -2.16%
## 3        Technology        NA  2.10%
## 4    IBM        IBM    130.00 -2.19%
## 5   AAPL      Apple     97.05 -2.48%
## 6   MSFT  Microsoft     50.99 -3.99%
formattable(DF, list(
  Name=formatter(
"span",
style = x ~ ifelse(x == "Technology", 
                   style(font.weight = "bold"), NA)),
  Value = color_tile("white", "orange")
 Change = formatter(
"span",
style = x ~ style(color = ifelse(x < 0 , "red", "green")),
x ~ icontext(ifelse(x < 0, "arrow-down", "arrow-up"), x))))
```

Comment: So you want to extract your table as an image and not as a html file right ?

Comment: Yes that's what I want

Comment: why don't you just feed powerbi with data then manipulate it inside?

Comment: Well, the thing is I'm making some advanced data processing in R like making cross tables but list of text inside the cell of the data frames instead of just 1 element ( by default in powerBI you just have 1 element in a cell and you can't have multiple elements in the cells of your tables). So I'm trying to render that on R and use the script to  show  results of my reports on Power BI

Comment: the `formattable()` call is not syntactically correct. you're missing a `,`.

Answer (score 3):

```
formattable(DF, list(
  Name = formatter(
    "span", style = x ~ ifelse(x == "Technology",  style(font.weight = "bold"), NA)
  ),
  Value = color_tile("white", "orange"),
  Change = formatter(
    "span", style = x ~ style(color = ifelse(x < 0 , "red", "green")),
    x ~ icontext(ifelse(x < 0, "arrow-down", "arrow-up"), x)))
) -> w

htmlwidgets::saveWidget(as.htmlwidget(w), "/some/dir/table.html", selfcontained = TRUE)

webshot::webshot(url = "/some/dir/table.html", file = "/some/dir/table.png", 
                 vwidth = 1000, vheight = 275)
```

[image]

The width/height is not necessarily going to come out precisely as what's specified and you'll need to do some manual guessing for it (or load up `magick` and see if you can auto-clip using it).

This relies on `phantomjs` and you may not be able to get your IT and/or security groups to enable the use of it.

Comment: I don't have admin rights so I don't think I'll be able to do it, but thanks for the answer anyways. I'll see what I can do with the IT group.