# How HTML div output can be saved as image?

Tags: html, css, r

I want to save output of HTML div as an image. Can we do it in rmarkdown or in R using any package like htmltools?

Like

```
<div class="w3-container w3-teal">
  <h1>My Header</h1>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution at [Convert html output to image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45298144/convert-html-output-to-image)

See also

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/webshot/webshot.pdf